# Page Transition in windows store application

Tags: windows-store-apps

I am developing windows store application, in which I want to incorporate page transitions(page entrance effects), when the other page is loaded or come to screen in response of an event in first screen. How can I do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this is an example how you can accomplish that..

`<Page.Transitions>
     <TransitionCollection>
        <EntranceThemeTransition />
      </TransitionCollection>
   </Page.Transitions>`